# Can a single Spring's KafkaConsumer listener listens to multiple messages from same/one partition?

Tags: java, spring, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, spring-kafka

Provided a topic having n partitions. 
Is there any way by which Spring's KafkaConsumer listener listens to multiple messages from same/one partition in one go?

I tried `ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory` by setting `setBatchListener(true);` but consumer has started consuming multiple messages from different partitions instead of one.

```
public class BatchReceiverConfig {

    @Value("${kafka.bootstrap-servers}")
    private String bootstrapServers;

    @Bean
    public Map<String, Object> consumerConfigs() {
        Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();

        props.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrapServers);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, "batch4");
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "earliest");
        // maximum records per batch receive
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.MAX_POLL_RECORDS_CONFIG, "10");

        return props;
    }

    @Bean
    public ConsumerFactory<String, String> consumerFactory() {
        return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(consumerConfigs());
    }

    @Bean
    public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> kafkaListenerContainerFactory() {
        ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> factory =
                new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
        factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory());
        factory.setConcurrency(2);
        // enable batch listeners
//        factory.setBatchListener(true);

        return factory;
    }

    @Bean
    public BatchReceiver receiver() {
        return new BatchReceiver();
    }
}


/* Listener */
@KafkaListener(id = "batch-listener", topics = TOPIC_TEST_BATCH)
    public void receive(List<String> data,
                        @Header(KafkaHeaders.RECEIVED_PARTITION_ID) List<Integer> partitions,
                        @Header(KafkaHeaders.OFFSET) List<Long> offsets) {

        LOGGER.info("start of batch receive");
        for (int i = 0; i < data.size(); i++) {
            LOGGER.info("received message='{}' with partition-offset='{}'", data.get(i),
                    partitions.get(i) + "-" + offsets.get(i));
            // handle message

            latch.countDown();
        }
        LOGGER.info("end of batch receive");
    }
```

Comment: To rephrase your question: "How can a single listener consume messages only from one partition?". Is that correct?

Comment: That's correct but in context of spring-kafka module.

Answer (score 0):

Provided there will be only one consumer in a group then you can set `concurrencyLevel` of that `ConcurrentKafkaListener` to `n`.

Comment: It didn't work and I believe 'max.poll.records' is the property which decides number of records to fetch.

Comment: Show me how do you configure Spring Kafka and Kafka consumer itself.

Comment: Have added snippet in question itself.

Answer (score 0):

If you use group management, Kafka will assign partitions to your consumers. Each consumer (or thread when using the concurrency) will get 0, 1, or more partitions, depending on how many consumers and partitions there are.

If you want a particular consumer to get messages from only one partition, you have to assign the partitions yourself instead of letting Kafka do the assignment.

If you use the concurrent container; you would have to assign the same number of partitions as the concurrency, so each thread only gets one partition.

Comment: In snippet posted in question, # of partitions = concurrency and even then its not working. Also, # of consumers = # of partitions.

Comment: If you are using group management, it will take time for the partitions to be distributed; initially, a consumer will get them all; the only guarantee is to assign the partitions yourself instead of using group management. `props.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, "batch4");`

Comment: In a clustered environment, its hard to define this as the same code is deployed to all nodes. Is there any way to configure it dynamically?

Comment: There is a [new option in the 0.11.0.0 client](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-4925) to delay partition allocation. We are working on adding support for that client. However, even with that, there is still no guarantee - if one of your instances dies, it's partitions will be redistributed. The only guarantee is to use manual assignment; you can use property placeholders; with each instance having different properties.